# ADT shortcuts for faster UI edit

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Is there any shortcut for editing properties of a widget in Android Layout editor in ADT?

I need to change gravity of TextView lots of times, but every time I have to use mouse...

Answer (score 0):

You could do a search and replace on a particular string in the layout.

> Highlight only the TextViews you want the search to happen in
>
> Search > Search
>
> Enter the string to be replaced and press the "Replace" button or "Replace
>   All" button.

If you post the exact xml listing of your layout, I can be more exact in which string needs to be replaced. If that solution doesn't work for your particular case, to save some time, I suppose you might also be able to create a particular custom Eclipse template for your TextView.

A third option would be to use inheritance and create a customTextView with the gravity already set a certain way.

And a fourth option still would be to set the properties of your TextViews programmatically after the fact using both XML and Java (instead of only using XML).